# geocodeAddress onload MVC Model.Address

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-maps

Basic geocodeAddress function direct from the GMaps Geocode API page has an "input textbox" and an "input submit" button. Instead I want the function to read my "Model.Address" and geocode --> produce map onload. Here is my latest attempt. I have re-written this in 20-30 different iterations with no luck. The "var address" declaration exposes the correct address on debugging, but the function is broken below that point...probably in the "{address: modaddress}" line or thereabouts. Any suggestions how to repair this appreciated. All samples and tutorials I see feature a search box and button. Thanks for any suggestion.

```
function initMap() {
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocodeAddress(geocoder, 'address');
    }

    function geocodeAddress(geocoder, address) {
        var modaddress = document.getElementById(@Model.Address).value;

            geocoder.geocode({
                'address': modaddress
            }, function (results, status) {
                if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                        zoom: 13,
                        center: results[0].geometry.location
                    });
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        position: results[0].geometry.location
                    });
                } else {
                    alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
                }
            });
    }
```

Comment: `var modaddress = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.FullAddress))`

Comment: Thanks much, Stephen. I felt like there was something wrong with the "getElementById" but didn't know how to alter. "Html.Raw" is an example of some gaps in my knowledge of j-scripting. I need to find a resource to learn more language and practice it. Thx again tho!